# Getting these errors while trying to build this repo/code?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Can Someone point me in the right direction about what this error is all about , as i'm fairly new to Java and all this building stuff.

the below Code is terminal output that is received after building

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-23 ~/j/java-NFTB (develop)> ./gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :protocol:compileJava
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/WalletGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/WalletExtensionGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/DatabaseGrpc.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/MonitorGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/nftbZksnarkGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/WalletSolidityGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/home/ubuntu/java-nftb/java-NFTB/protocol/src/main/java/org/nftb/api/NetworkGrpc.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
7 errors

> Task :protocol:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':protocol:compileJava'.
```

Sorry, if i've made any mistakes please feel free to correct me as i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to build.gradle file and make sure you have all the dependencies you need .

for example , here you are missing this

```
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
```

You can add and try to rebuild again , also please make sure to add the build.gradle code for next time .